# Returning an Array from a method (doesn't seem to be working)

Tags: java, methods

import java.util.*;

public class test2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] list2 = reverse(list);
 System.out.print(list2);
}

public static int[] reverse(int[] list){
    int[] result = new int[list.length];

    for(int i=0, j=list.length-1; i<list.length; i++,j--){
        result[j] = list[i];}

    return result;  }

}
```

it is a code from my textbook.
But when I print list2, it shows this weird message : [I@7b963273
I have no idea what is wrong with the code.
Plz help me!

Answer (score 1):

The array of primitive types is an object itself . When you print it using System.out.print() , it calls [toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29) method of Object class.
Which is defined like this in Object class:

```
public String  toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

to print the returned array you use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2));
```

**EDIT**
If you want to return an array from method you should do exactly how you did in your code.

> suppose that 'merge' is a method and arr1 and arr2 are arrays then you can do like this:

```
public static int[] merge(int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
  int[] result = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
  int counter = 0 ;
  for ( int i =0 ;i < result.length ; i++)
  {
    if ( i >= arr1.length)
    {
      result[i] = arr2[counter++];
    }
    else
    {
      result[i] = arr1[i];
    }
  }
 return result;
}
```

And then you can print the merge as:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merge(arr1,arr2));
```

Comment: if I want to get an array from a method, then what should i do?

Comment: suppose that 'merge' is a method and arr1 and arr2 are arrays, System.out.println(merge(arr1, arr2)); -> this doesn't seem to work in a similar fashion with my previous problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `toString()` (implicitly) directly on an array. Arrays don't override `toString()`, so you get the [default implementation from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

So in your output, the `[I` part is the "name" of the `int[]` class (print `int[].class.getName()` and it will show the same thing) and the number is the hash code of the array in hex. (Which again isn't overridden - it doesn't take account of the contents of tha array.)

This has nothing to do with where the array has come from - you'd get the same kind of output (with a different number) if you called:

```
System.out.print(list);
```

before the `reverse` call.

You should use [`Arrays.toString(int\[\])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2));
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(list2);` invokes `Object#toString()` method which returns the combination of `Classname+@+Hex_Number_Of_Hashcode` .

you have to use overloaded [`Arrays.toString(list2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29); to print the string representation of your array.